Would it be legal to promise a bribe to future jurors long before one commits any crime?
Let's say one is a billionaire living in California. In 2024 they post the following message on their personal website:

I have never committed any crimes and have no intention to commit any. But if I'm ever put on a jury trial and found 'not guilty', I promise to pay $10 million in Bitcoin to any juror who asks for payment after the trial is over.

Would this be legal, assuming they're indeed not guilty of any crimes as of 2024?

I don't think it makes a difference at which time you offer a bribe, nor whether you have been convicted earlier or not. That's like saying "Since I'm a billionaire, I can buy justice", which obviously isn't (or shouldn't be) the case in a working jurisdiction.

@PMF "...in a working jurisdiction". But OP is asking about America ;-)

@PMF Actually making an effort to suborn a future jury is illegal, but not every statement that one intends some illegal thing is itself illegal. This is usually encountered in the context of "true threats" but it might apply to "true bribery" in a like manner.

By posting that, they just committed a crime
new-south-wales
The crime is, of course bribery.

The offence can be constituted by the mere offer of a corrupt inducement, even if the offer is rejected: R v Glynn (1994) 33 NSWLR 139 at 144, 146. It can also be intended to influence future conduct; the occasion for the disregard of duty need not have arisen at the time of the offence, and it need never arise: R v Allen (1992) 27 NSWLR 398 at 402.


Does this work if you can't name a specific person to whom this offer could apply? Said billionaire might be put on trial in 50 years from now, with all the jury members still yet to be born.

@JonathanReez Why would that matter? If I bribe a beat cop I don't recognize or I hand some money to a shadowy go-between or I slip an envelope marked "to whom it may concern" under a door at City Hall, it's still passing a bribe. Knowing who you're bribing is immaterial so long as you believe, or it would be reasonable for you to believe, that they can do what you want.

If you post a reward notice for the return of your lost iguana, Kennith, you are making a valid and legally binding offer to the world. Anyone who shows up with Kennith can claim the reward. Except that bribery is illegal and therefore can’t be the subject of a binding contract, the same applies here.

@Cadence  "to whom it may concern"  could still be mapped to an actual, specific person. A generic statement made to a jury that might not yet even be born is a different level.

@JonathanReez but we know exactly who these people are - they are the people on the jury in the billionaire's trial. Just because we don't yet know their names doesn't make them unidentified.
